# Isomorphism and its effects on function composition

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, vector-spaces

In a proof the professor did this while talking about the transformation matrix

$$ \Phi_{A'} \circ \tilde{T}_{A'}^{A} = id_V \circ \Phi_{A} = \Phi_{A} \rightarrow \quad \tilde{T}_{A'}^{A} = \Phi_{A'}^{-1}  \circ \Phi_{A}$$

He basically just put $\Phi_{A'}$ on the other side, much like an algebraic transformation and said he was allowed to do it, because all the linear mappings above are isomorphisms.

**Could somebody elaborate, why isomorphisms allow you do that?**

Comment: Should that be $\tilde{T}_{A'}^A=\Phi_{A'}^{-1}\circ\Phi_A$?

Comment: Yes, you are correct, not only that, I think that answered my question. He just takes the inverse ( which he is allowed to do, because isomorphisms are bijective ) and the result follows. Is that correct?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since $\Phi_{A'}$ is an isomorphism, $id = \Phi^{-1}_{A'}\circ\Phi_{A'}$. Hence,
$$\tilde{T}_{A'}^A = id\circ \tilde{T}_{A'}^A = \Phi^{-1}_{A'}\circ\Phi_{A'}\circ \tilde{T}_{A'}^A \overset{!}{=} \Phi^{-1}_{A'}\circ\Phi_A.$$
The equality (!) used the fact that $\Phi_{A'}\circ\tilde{T}_{A'}^A = \Phi_A$.

Comment: Sorry for the typo there, small but important mistake! Thank your for being so thorough

Comment: @JonathanZ Glad I could help!